# IIS basic auth against database TABLE

Tags: iis, sql-server, asp-classic

I have a site on IIS where the auth is being done by having a header included in all (classic ) asp pages, if session variables is not set, user is redirected to login page, setting the session variables if user is in sql table.
However, this does not protect ressources like images and javascripts which are without that header file.

So is it possible to use basic authentification to perform a sql lookup in a user table on the IIS server?

NOTE: the users are NOT sql users, they are just entries in a regular table.

Comment: Windows/IIS only supports Basic authentication against Active Directory. If you want something else, you have to develop your own IIS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is possible to write a module for external auth:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication#basic-authentication-with-custom-membership